# Where can I find SF reviews?

Tags: online-resources

What are good places on the web to find reviews of SF books, movies, etc.?

A good review site:

- explains why one might or might not like a work, not just listing synopses
- offers many reviews to choose from
- makes it easy to search for the works you may be interested in
- provides ways to get an impression of whether you'll agree with a particular reviewer

Please contribute the review sites that you like. Amalgamated sites that collect reviews from many people are preferred. Series from a particular reviewer are also ok, but please don't post links to single reviews.

Answers are sorted by media; please add to the existing answer for each media.

Answer (score 8):

### Some great sites for SF book reviews

- [SFRevu](http://www.sfrevu.com/) has a fair number of reviews.
- [SF Crowsnest](http://www.sfcrowsnest.com/articles/books/zoo/home_books.php) has lots of reviews.
- I particularly like the reviews at [Strange Horizons](http://www.strangehorizons.com/), although they review only three books per week.
- It seems that [SF Site](http://www.sfsite.com/) is running fewer reviews than it used to, but there are still a fair number.
- [Tor.com](http://www.tor.com/) is a community hub sponsored by the largest US SF publisher. They have a fair number of reviews (books from all publishers -- the reviewers don't favor the home team). Jo Walton is an exceptionally perspicacious reader.
- [SF Signal](http://www.sfsignal.com/) is an SF news site that runs a few book book reviews (maybe 2 per week), but their daily roundup includes links to reviews on other sites.
- I know it doesn't fit all of your criteria, but it you're interested in SF book reviews, you should check out [*Locus*](http://www.locusmag.com/). It has been the best single source for SF book news for decades. The magazine reviews dozens of books each month. Unfortunately, they post only a few reviews to the web, and digital issues (pdf, mobi, & epub) have been available only since January 2011. The website also has:

  - Very good coverage of other SF publications, including what they review.
  - Links to reviews in non-SF outlets.
  - A very good list of [SF links](http://www.locusmag.com/Links/index.html) (scroll down to "Reviews, Interviews, Commentary")
  - An [index](http://www.locusmag.com/Magazine/Reviews0.html) of reviews in the print magazine
  - A comprehensive index to [SF awards](http://www.locusmag.com/SFAwards/index.html).

Comment: Hasn't Strange Horizons closed down?

Comment: @apoorv020: No, the most recent content at Strange Horizons is dated 27 June, 2011. Maybe you're thinking of Salon Futura, which went on hiatus last month. Or SciFiDimensions or The Internet Review of Science Fiction, which both closed last year.

Comment: Actually, I was thinking of [Speculative Horizons](http://speculativehorizons.blogspot.com/). It closed last december.

Answer (score 4):

## Books and short stories

### Large collections

- [**Amazon**](http://www.amazon.com/Science-Fiction-Fantasy-Books/b/ref=bhp_bb0309A_scfifa2_A?ie=UTF8&node=25) has reviews for the books they sell, but the reviews tend to be unreliable.
- [**Goodreads**](http://www.goodreads.com) - A free social network based around books, has aggregated book ratings etc.
- [**ISFDB**](https://www.isfdb.org/) has extensive bibliographic information and occasional reviews of books and stories.
- [**LibraryThing**](http://www.librarything.com/) allows people to share book lists and reviews.
- The [Usenet group **rec.arts.sf.written**](http://groups.google.com/groups/search?q=review&as_ugroup=rec.arts.sf.written) has tens of thousands of reviews.

### Topical collections

- [Millennial reviews](http://www.cloggie.org/esseff/millennial-reviews.html): reviews of books set in or very close to 2000, by James Nicoll

### Reviewer blogs

- [James Nicoll](http://james-nicoll.livejournal.com/?skip=20) reviews many new books (but not always on his blog)
- [Pat's Fantasy Hotlist](http://fantasyhotlist.blogspot.com/)

Comment: I'm hesitant to accept Amazon as a source of reliable reviews. A quick look at the jobs on many writing bid sites shows that online product reviews can be bought.

Answer (score 2):

#### Movies

### Large collections

- [**IMDB**](http://www.imdb.com/) indexes just about every movie and carries user reviews.
- [**Metacritic**](http://www.metacritic.com/movies) collects movie reviews.
- [**Rotten Tomatoes**](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/) rates movies, and links to reviews.